# How to communicate effectively with a customer if I have low self-esteem and I have doubts about the value that I or our company can deliver?

Tags: customer-service, psychology

I am trying to do my best but my self-esteem is low and I feel the risks that I can become rude (e.g. avoid normal pleasantries) because my personal value is so low that noone can be insulted by such small creature as me whatever I am doing. Or, even worth, I can become paternalistic if there is any chance that I can deliver some value however. Or I am not sure I can deliver enough value to satisfy the customer needs.

What should I do? From time to time I am consulting with psychotherapist but up to now my psychotherapist has not identified the need for intervention regarding this area although I am bringing this problem quite frequently in our sessions.

Comment: You have a sales position?

Comment: No, I am developer and from time to time I have to consult our customers regarding software fetures which we are developing.

Comment: You don't have a go between? Customer contract manager or something similar?

Comment: Ww have good dedicated service staff but from time to time I should step in.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the actual problem is not job related, but a personal situation which can be improved with the help of professional support (therapy, coaching, training, practice, experience...).

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to approach this - the first as others have said is to simply ask the company not to involve you in Customer Facing interactions.

This is certainly an option, however I'm going to recommend against it.

We don't grow as people and in confidence (Foreshadowing...) by retreating from things that are difficult - we gain confidence by voluntarily doing those things that we struggle with.

Therefore, I'm going to suggest the opposite - there's an old phrase about this:

"Fake it till you make it"

That is, you pretend to be confident, put on a veneer and play a part as an actor until such time that you really are confident.

"Ah MrDemonLord - it's all very well to say that, but how do I do that?!"

Firstly - you will need to prep, if you know that you have a client meeting at say 10 am, then you need to spend at least from 8:30 am -9:30 am prepping.

Re-read the customers' design brief, re-read the code, double check for any email updates, check in with the project manager and sales team, write out some notes of points you want to discuss.

You want to walk into that meeting knowing it back-to-front - this will help with the illusion of confidence. Also - Chance favors the Prepared Mind.

Next up is your manner - be friendly, try to appear calm and when you choose to speak, you want to use concise (but not clipped) and decisive language - use absolutes and definitive statements - avoid things that suggest doubt.

e.g. "We could do it like this or we could do it like that" - No.

"There are several potential solutions, but based on your requirements, we will do it this way" = Yes.

And most importantly - at the end of the discussion you want to articulate your main action points - these can be as much or as little as required - however if it grows much beyond say 5, you may want to consolidate them. Generally, 3 key takeaways from a Meeting is a good amount.

The first few times is gonna suck. This is normal - first it's going to be a conscious effort to do it, then it will be something that is routine, then it will become a Habit then it will integrate into your personality and you WILL be that confident person.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation it's best to leave all the client facing stuff to those trained to handle it. You just don't have the training and confidence to make a good effort of it. And as a developer you shouldn't need it.

So ideally the client never contacts you directly. If this isn't possible then always have your service rep in the loop, this will share the burden, you will be the tech expert without a need to worry about keeping the customer happy and the trained service rep will do the happy customer things.

Comment: While it is nice suggestion, I would be more happy to grow as a person and develop my skills and personality and not to remain in the suboptimal development stage which is clearly not good for me. But, thanks, anyway, for the reply!

Comment: Thats something you need to work out through therapy or personally, I'm just trying to get you through until you're ok to tackle everything head on. Confidence in your work comes with time and experience. Not automatically for many people, but it does come.

Answer (score 1):

If talking to a customer, try to think as "We, the company", not "I, the developer". Leave the personal baggage behind.

If your self esteem is low because you get a lot of negative feedback from customers, try a frame challenge: If you have 100 customers and 90 of them are perfectly content with your product. You will never hear a word from them. The 10 customers who are not satisfied will contact you daily. So hearing negative stuff all day doesn't say something about your or your products value.

In my opinion what you say sounds quite dark. "I'm so small that noone can be bothered with me". This is no normal mindset. Think about it: A customer contacts your company because you can provide a service that he needs. So obviously you do something useful.

Comment: And it also helps to check with a manager as to what to say and then, simply state "here is the company's position". I had doubts in one case and simply stated "my orders are to say X."